# GeoJSON will load from variable, but not from file in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, json

I'm trying to add a point to my open layers map from a file.

To start with I loaded the json data from a variable.

```
var data = '{ "type": "Feature", "geometry" : { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [-252000, -592000], [314000, 64000] ] } }'

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data, {
    }),
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
        vectorLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: ukProj,
        center: [0.5*(imageExtent[2]+imageExtent[0]),0.5*(imageExtent[3]+imageExtent[1])],
        zoom: 7,
    })
});
```

This works successfully. Now I'm trying to load the data from a json file, my file looks like this  (same as variable input):

```
{ "type": "Feature", "geometry" : { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [-252000, -592000], [314000, 64000] ] } }
```

And I'm loading it like this:

```
geojsonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "https://path_to_data/data.json",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
        geojsonLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: ukProj,
        center: [0.5*(imageExtent[2]+imageExtent[0]),0.5*(imageExtent[3]+imageExtent[1])],
        zoom: 7,
    })
});
```

But the point is nowhere to be seen on my map. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your projection is different in your second code block `ukProj`. Is that supposed to be `ukngProj`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It was correct in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used in a Vector source the GeoJSON parser will attempt to transform coordinates from the default data projection for GeoJSONs (CRS:84) to the view projection.  As your coordinates are already in the view projection you should set that in the format options:

```
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: ukProj})
```

Comment: That's got it working. Thank you!